# Azure emulator storage installation error

Tags: azure, azure-storage-emulator

I've installed Windows Azure SDK v2.2, all good.

But when I'm trying to launch Windows Azure Emulator v.2.2 it asks me to browse `emulator.6492.fre.rd_dk_stable_v2r2.130926-0939-x64.msi` package.

I don't have it on my machine and I don't know where to get it.

Who did also face to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling?  Did you install the SDK via the Web Platform Installer?

Comment: Same problem... Did you get to the bottom of it?

Comment: I tried uninstalling and installing again both manually and through web platform installer - still got the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to reinstall it at least 3 times. I installed it through web platform installer too.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I've used for this is:

1. Start Windows Azure Command Prompt as an admin
2. Enter `csrun /devstore:start`

It seems that it all works fine behind the scenes, it's just the shortcut that's broken.

Comment: Interesting, it starts, but then I get another error "The storage emulator had an unexpected error: Unable to detect SQL Version". It's wierd, because my colleague installed it the same way without any problem. I checked it out I have Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDb on my machine.

Comment: Are you a local admin? Can you connect to (localdb)\v11.0?

Comment: @shkiper - what happens if you run DSInit in Azure command prompt?

Comment: No, I'm not. It just prompts me to logon as an administrator. But when I do "DSInit" it writes 

Found SQL Instance (localdb)\v11.0.
Creating database DevelopmentStorageDb22 on SQL instance '(localdb)\v11.0'.
Granting database access to user toffee\Administrator.
Database access for user toffee\Administrator was granted.
Initialization successful. The storage emulator is now ready for use.

And when I try to connect to localDb I see it again "Unable to detect SQL Version"

Answer (score 0):

Another option, create a shortcut to **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csmonitor.exe** onto your taskbar. Then start it in admin mode by **CTRL + SHIFT** clicking it.